# How do I condense a pandas data frame where the rows are the months and I'm trying to condense them into years?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

So I have a dataframe

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ssG8bvkZKVDR6V5yU9fZVRJbJNfTTEYmWqLwmDwBa0/edit#gid=0

This is the out put that my code gives.

Here is the code:

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/User/Downloads/Div Tickers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

tickers_list = df['Ticker'].tolist()
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickers_list)


yahoo_financials_ecommerce = YahooFinancials(data)

ecommerce_income_statement_data = yahoo_financials_ecommerce.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'income')

data = ecommerce_income_statement_data['incomeStatementHistory']

df_dict = dict()

for ticker in tickers_list:

    df_dict[ticker] = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data[ticker][x]) for x in range(len(data[ticker]))],
               sort=False, join='outer', axis=1)

df = pd.concat(df_dict, sort=True)

df_l = pd.DataFrame(df.stack())
df_l.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_l.columns = ['ticker', 'financials', 'date', 'value']

df_w = df_l.pivot_table(index=['date.year', 'financials'], columns='ticker', values='value')


export_excel = df_w.to_excel(r'C:/Users/User/Downloads/Income Statement Histories.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1", index= True)
```

How would I go about condensing the months into years so that the data is comparable Year-over-Year?

Comment: please add a subset of your data as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need to melt, then use `groupby` on your date column to group by year.

```
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['date','financials'],var_name='ticker')

df.groupby([df['date'].dt.year,df['financials'],df['ticker']])['value'].sum().unstack()

ticker                                      AEM          AGI           ALB  \
date financials                                                              
2016 costOfRevenue                 1.030000e+09  309000000.0  1.710000e+09   
     discontinuedOperations        0.000000e+00          0.0  2.020000e+08   
     ebit                          3.360000e+08   21300000.0  5.370000e+08   
     grossProfit                   1.110000e+09  173000000.0  9.700000e+08   
     incomeBeforeTax               2.680000e+08   -7600000.0  5.750000e+08   
...                                         ...          ...           ...   
2019 researchDevelopment           0.000000e+00          0.0  5.828700e+07   
     sellingGeneralAdministrative  1.210000e+08   19800000.0  4.390000e+08   
     totalOperatingExpenses        1.650000e+09  557000000.0  2.830000e+09   
     totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet   -1.000000e+08    2900000.0 -6.900000e+07   
     totalRevenue                  2.490000e+09  683000000.0  3.590000e+09
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for responding. Is there any way to keep the structure (with the tickers running along the top of the dataframe)? What I was hoping for was something like: the year and then in the second column have the nae of all the items of the income statement and then all the tickers are on the top row. Then in the first column, in the 19th row, the 2017 year starts. and so on :)

Comment: OMG. This is exactly the output I'm looking for!!!!!! When I run it on my own I get: "KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['date']""

Comment: is your date your index ? try `df.reset_index()` first @JacobSteenhuysen

Comment: we are so so so close. I'm not sure how your output is soooooo perfect. This is what I get when I try it your way: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzHvq7trkeKGaf0zD_Tscto9huxZXm0dZ2bfSmfqew0/edit?usp=sharing           but your output is sooooo perfect

Answer (score 0):

Not sure since you didn't give us any data, but you can change a datetime column to year with the following code. The first bit is just generating some smaple data:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randint

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates': [datetime.today() - timedelta(randint(0, 1000)) for _ in range(50)]
})

print(df.head())

                       dates
0 2019-09-02 21:01:46.702300
1 2019-11-03 21:01:46.702329
2 2019-04-01 21:01:46.702338
3 2019-03-04 21:01:46.702345
4 2019-03-28 21:01:46.702351
```

The part that matters

```
df.dates.dt.to_period('Y')

0     2018
1     2018
2     2019
3     2018
4     2019
5     2020
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I put the dataframe into the google sheets file. Im sorry I wasnt clear. When I do it this way, all the financial data is lost though.